# Spotify WebPlayer API - Change Player Request

Tags: reactjs, fetch, jsx, spotify

I've been working on a Spotify player using React, and so far I've been able to get the player to properly connect to the API and receive a device_id.

My next step is change the player to the newly "made" one, but I keep on receiving `400: Required field device_ids missing`, even though I have it included in the `PUT` request:

```js
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken 
    }, 
    data: {
        "device_ids": [device_id],
        "play": 'true'
    }
};

// Change player
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player', requestOptions)
```

Am I missing something/formatting it incorrectly? I've tried changing the `data` to `body` and I instead get a `400: Malformed JSON`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the following format:

```js
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        device_ids: [southORadioDevId],
        play: 'true'
    }),
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${spotifyAccessToken}`
    },
};

// Change player
fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player', requestOptions)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to use JSON.stringify to resolve my problem and this helped!